# How do I install the gnome-keybinding-properties program?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 and quickly ditched Unity. I followed a tutorial containing instructions for getting Gnome set up properly but I am stuck without the "Keyboard Shortcuts" program in System->Preferences.

I know the command for this program is "gnome-keybinding-properties" but I don't know what package the program belongs to.

Running the command yields:

```
gnome-keybinding-properties: command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gnome-keybinding-properties was provided by gnome-control-center before 11.10, that means this application was provided with Gnome2. In Gnome 3 (so with 11.10) you can't find this application with this name. Instead, use Gnome Control Center's Keyboard section (Shortcuts tab).

Answer (score 5):

For resume, use this commandline [Gnome 3]:

```
gnome-control-center keyboard
```

Comment: Para resumir => To resume

Comment: Para resumir => To summarize